# Javascript strange date manipulation

Tags: javascript, date

I came across in a seemingly reputable source a strange date manipulation that I don't understand. This is part of the samples in supporting documentation for a popular UI framework:

```
var startDate = start.value();  // returns Date object
startDate = new Date(startDate);
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
```

Now line by line `var startDate = start.value();` this lines returns Date object and saves it in `startDate` variable. Fine here, no problem.

Then we create new Date object with the same value and assign it back to the same variable (mildly confusing, but I can live with it).

Third line is a real puzzle - we get day of the month (via `getDate`) and assign it as a day of the month (via `setDate`) in the same variable.

Now the question: is this a bad code, possibly leftovers from unfinished refactoring? Or is this really making sense and it does some manipulation like removing time (does not look like it)? If it is, what does it do?

**UPD**: code sample is here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/rangeselection

Comment: Is this legacy code for a specific browser? Other than that option I can't think of any possible reason to do that.

Comment: @Nit code sample - nothing about legacy or browsers

Comment: It appears (at least when I run it in Chrome's console) to be creating multiple new date objects. If there's no specific purpose, then this code is actually quite inefficient.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/rangeselection

Comment: Seems very similar to [this other page](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/datetimepicker/rangeselection) that does a +1 in the `setDate`.  Perhaps it was a simple copy/paste and refactor to force end to be at most the same as the start, rather than the day after.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes, indeed. Just found it as well. In my code sample it should be `+1` or `-1` on the `getDate()`

Comment: @JamesThorpe do you mind putting this into an answer, so we can close this topic

Comment: This can be confirmed by looking at the jsp or php version of the same code, it has the +1

Comment: It's only my speculation.  You'd need to ask whoever wrote that specific example really, making this Q opinion based - we can only guess at their intentions/potential mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source is available in multiple formats, and if we inspect them all:

html5/javascript:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
```

asp.net:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
```

jsp:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
```

php:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
```

We can clearly see the first (one you linked to) stands out where they should be the same. This would lead one to believe the issue is a simple typo.

Answer (score 2):

Lets go line by line:

```
startDate = new Date(startDate);
```

Will return the same date if `startDate` is a `Date`

```js
var someDate = new Date(5555555113);
console.log(someDate);
startDate = new Date(someDate);
console.log(startDate);
```

But if `start.value()` returns either  miliseconds, or a string, passing it to `new Date` will ensure whatever of these 3 ways to represent a `Date` is used, you'll get the `Date` object.

```js
var someDate = 5555555113;
var startDate = new Date(someDate);
console.log(startDate);

someDate = "1970-03-06T07:12:35.113Z";
startDate = new Date(someDate);
console.log(startDate);
```

Now the next line:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
```

This doesn't make any sense, as it'll return the same `Date`

```js
var startDate = new Date();
console.log(startDate);
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate())
console.log(startDate);
```